# Config Server using Database as repository

Tags: configuration, cloud, spring-cloud

Currently we are maintaining all our properties in the database and applications are referenced through their Spring Profile Name , now we are transitioning into Cloud Foundry, keeping this in focus how can we build Spring Cloud Config Server using existing database to read application properties, so far in the documentation i see reference to Git Repository

http://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-config/spring-cloud-config.html#_spring_cloud_config_server

Answer (score 0):

Not currently, we are limited to git and svn. There is a pull request for [mongodb](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-config/pull/289) for an example though.

Comment: any idea when this will be supported, also if you have any examples of SVN based repository? currently we have multiple db instances for dev,test & prod which maintains environment specific application properties, so if we happen to use SVN backed repository how do we split the svn folders when i have tables joins ex., we built application specific and also shared properties, so shared property tables are joined with application specific tables

Answer (score 0):

No longer true, now support is available for jdbc http://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-config/single/spring-cloud-config.html#_jdbc_backend